# complex number rotation and negation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Given

[image]

I have 2 questions.

1. How do I calculate $e^{-i\nu_j}$ with $\zeta_{j+1}$ and $\zeta_j$
2. Is $-i$ on the RHS is really required ? I get the correct value from python when $-i$ is not there. could this be a typo ?

This is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75538966/numpy-eitheta-and-trigonometric-costheta-isintheta-does-not-match

I'am having a difficulty understanding why my numerical results are different from above.

Thanks

REF: "[The Complex Variable Boundary Element Method for Potential Flow Problems](https://www.witpress.com/Secure/elibrary/papers/BEM06/BEM06022FU1.pdf)" -- Miroslav Mokry

Comment: Please explain what the right hand side of your expression means.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-discourage-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) will help you recognize and resolve the issues.

Comment: Can you take $1/$ the right hand side?

Comment: Thanks @WindSoul ; could you please share your thoughts if the equation in the above snippet is indeed correct  ? is "i" in the RHS applicable - could it be a typo ?

Comment: @NotaMathematician I can't judge what you want to do, and so whether there should be the $-i$. Do you actually want to find the $ϑ$ in [your linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75538966/4780451), the angle of $\zeta_{j+1}-\zeta_j$? Or do you still want to find $\nu_j$, the angle of $-i(\zeta_{j+1}-\zeta_j)$?

Comment: HI @peterwhy this is actually from paper : "The Complex Variable Boundary Element Method for Potential Flow Problems" -- Miroslav Mokry. Above equation is Eq-21 from that paper. Basically I am interested in finding the value of e−iνj

Comment: I've added a REF to that paper on the question. - Thanks

Comment: A quick (and irresponsible) glance in your REF shows that in Figure 1(b), angle $\nu_j$ is the angle of normal, not the angle of just $\zeta_{j+1}-\zeta_j$. (Also already suggested in an earlier [stackoverflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75538966/numpy-eitheta-and-trigonometric-costheta-isintheta-does-not-match/75539941#comment133276131_75538966)) This might explain why there's the $-i$ factor in your question image.

Comment: $e^{-i\nu_j}= \cos \nu_j - i \sin \nu_j = i \frac{|\zeta_{j+1}-\zeta_j|}{\zeta_{j+1}-\zeta_j}$.

Comment: May be you are new to using forums. Using ALLCAPS in a forum is the equivalent to screaming in person, you should avoid that.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @jjagmath, I've removed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First about question 2: your intention.

From page 212 of your REF, Figure 1(b) and the introduction below defines angle $\nu$ to be the angle of normal, not the angle of just $\zeta_{j+1}-\zeta_j$.

In contrast, in [your linked stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75538966/4780451), that OP focuses on an angle $\vartheta$ -- the angle of $\zeta_{j+1}-\zeta_j$. This might explain why there's the $-i$ factor in your question image, if the goal is still to find $\nu$ (instead of $\vartheta$). The $-i$ factor rotates the angle clockwise by $\pi/2$.

---

Now, as $e^{i\nu_j}$ is defined as

$$e^{i\nu_j} = -i \frac{\zeta_{j+1}-\zeta_j}{\left|\zeta_{j+1}-\zeta_j\right|},$$

the required $e^{-i\nu_j}$ is simply the reciprocal of $e^{i\nu_j}$:

$$\begin{align*}
e^{-i\nu_j} &= \frac{1}{e^{i\nu_j}}\\
&= \cfrac{1}{-i \cfrac{\zeta_{j+1}-\zeta_j}{\left|\zeta_{j+1}-\zeta_j\right|}}\\
&= i \frac{\left|\zeta_{j+1}-\zeta_j\right|}{\zeta_{j+1}-\zeta_j}
\end{align*}$$

Or if you already calculated $e^{i\nu_j} = -i \frac{\zeta_{j+1}-\zeta_j}{\left|\zeta_{j+1}-\zeta_j\right|}$ (e.g. in numpy), then perform the division $1/e^{i\nu_j}$ to get $e^{-i\nu_j}$.

Comment: Thanks Peter. You are a life saver. Thanks for pointing out my mistake. Really appreciate the assistance and time you spent on this :) I've verified this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to verify that

$$(1) \quad |e^{i\theta}|=1, \quad \forall \theta \in \cal R,$$

$$(2) \quad e^{-i\theta} = \frac{ 1}{e^{i\theta}}.$$

1. Assuming the $\zeta$'s are real (are they?), (1) and (2) imply that

$$e^{-i\nu_j}= \cos \nu_j - i \sin \nu_j = i \frac{\zeta_{j+1}-\zeta_j}{|\zeta_{j+1}-\zeta_j|}$$

2. Hard to say unless you tell us what $\nu_j$ and $\zeta_j, \zeta_{j+1}$ are.

### UPDATE

If $\zeta$'s are complex, as you say, then

$$e^{-i\nu_j}= \cos \nu_j - i \sin \nu_j = i \frac{\overline{\zeta}_{j+1}-\overline{\zeta}_j}{|\zeta_{j+1}-\zeta_j|}, \quad \text{ where } \overline{\zeta} = \text{Re}( \zeta ) - i \,\text{Im}(\zeta)$$

Comment: Hi @mjw ; Thanks much. ζs are complex. These are points in 2d plane represented as complex numbers. Detailed description are in the linked question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75538966/numpy-eitheta-and-trigonometric-costheta-isintheta-does-not-match

Comment: νj are the angles these points create with the real axis

Comment: Hi @mjw ; I've also added a REF to the paper I was referring to .

Comment: Thanks${}{}{}{}{}$